# Clicking specific class to trigger open modal event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How can I fix this? I have used PHP to display data from my database but I didn't foresee this bug. When I click the edit the modal will appear However, when I click the edit button of the other data the modal will not appear. How can I fix this? What I want is when I click the edit button modal will appear. I hope you can help me its been bugging me for days.

Edit Button.

[image: Edit Button HERE]

Please See Modal.

[image: Please See Modal HERE]

Here is my code:

**PHP:**

```
echo "<div class='col-3'>";
                        echo "<div class='card'>";
                        echo "<div class='row'>";
                        echo "<div class='col-2'>";
                        echo "<h6 class='card-title'>".$row['project_name']."</h6>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='col-2'>";
                        echo "<div class='card-setting'><i class='fa fa-gear'></i></div>";
                        echo "<div id='card-setting-dropdown' class='card-dropdown-content'>";
                        echo "<button class='card-dropdown-menu' id='btn-edit'>Edit Project</button>";
                        echo "<button class='card-dropdown-menu'>Delete Project</button>";
                        echo "<button class='card-dropdown-menu'>Add Task</button>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='row'>";
                        echo "<div class='col-2'>";
                        echo "<label  class='project-details'>".$row['department']."</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='col-2'>";
                        echo "<label class='project-details' style='float:right;'>Priority: <span style='color:".$color."'>".$row['priority']."</span></label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='pr-task-data'>";
                        echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-l'>";
                        echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>Tasks</label>";
                        echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>".$count_2."</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-l'>";
                        echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>Completed</label>";
                        echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>".$count_3."</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-l'>";
                        echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>In-Progress</label>";
                        echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>".$count_4."</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-r'>";
                        echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>Not Completed</label>";
                        echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>".$count_5."</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='progress'>";
                        echo "<div class='progress-bar' style='width:".$percent."%;'>";
                        echo "<label class='progress-bar-percent'>".$percent."%</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";

                        echo "<div id='modal_2' class='modal fade'>";
                        echo "<div class='modal-dialog'>";
                        echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
                        echo "<div class='modal-header'>";
                        echo "<h6 class='modal-title'>Add Project</h6>";
                        echo "<button type='button' class='close_2'>x</button>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='modal-body'>";
                        echo "<form autocomplete='off' method='POST'>";
                        echo "<input type='hidden' id='".$row['project_id']."'>";
                        echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                        echo "<label class='form-control-label'>Program</label>";
                        echo "<input type='text' placeholder='Program' name='program' id='program_2' class='form-control'>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                        echo "<label class='form-control-label'>Project Name</label>";
                        echo "<input type='text' placeholder='Project Name' name='pname' id='pname' class='form-control'>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                        echo "<label class='form-control-label'>Project Description</label>";
                        echo "<input type='text' placeholder='Description' name='description' id='description' class='form-control'>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                        echo "<label class='form-control-label'>Department</label>";
                        echo "<select class='form-control' id='department' name='department'>";
                        echo "<option value=''>Department</option>";
                        echo "<option value='Executive Department'>Executive Department</option>";
                        echo "<option value='CCA Department'>CCA Department</option>";
                        echo "</select>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                        echo "<label class='form-control-label'>Priority</label>";
                        echo "<select class='form-control' id='priority' name='priority'>";
                        echo "<option value=''>Priority</option>";
                        echo "<option value='Low'>Low</option>";
                        echo "<option value='Medium'>Medium</option>";
                        echo "<option valie='High'>High</option>";
                        echo "<option valie='High'>High</option>";
                        echo "</select>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='modal-footer'>";
                        echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-update' name='update'>Update</button>";
                        echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary'>Close</button>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</form>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
//Edit Project Modal
var modal_edit = document.getElementById('modal_2');
var btn_edit = document.getElementById("btn-edit");
var span_edit = document.getElementsByClassName("close_2")[0];

btn_edit.onclick = function() { 
    $(modal_edit).toggleClass("modal-show");
}

span_edit.onclick = function() {
    $(modal_edit).removeClass("modal-show");    
}

$(".btn-secondary").click(function() {
    $(modal_edit).removeClass("modal-show");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

1. Add a common class to your edit button Like `class="btnEdit other_classes"`
2. Try this code

   ```
   var modal_edit = document.getElementById('modal_2');
   var span_edit = document.getElementsByClassName("close_2")[0];

   // I assumed that your button is added dynamically
   $(document).on('click',".btnEdit",function(){
       $(modal_edit).toggleClass("modal-show");
   });

   span_edit.onclick = function() {
       $(modal_edit).removeClass("modal-show");    
   }

   $(".btn-secondary").click(function() {
       $(modal_edit).removeClass("modal-show");
   });
   ```

Your Click is not working for other elements because you are using `id` to assign events with them but and `id` must be unique. I made sample fiddle with two elements with the same ID's and try to look at their difference..

```js
$("#first").click(function(){
  alert("I was clicked");
});
```

```css
div{
display:inline-block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">DIV</div>
<div id="first">DIV</div>
```

The first one only works.. So use `class` instead..

Comment: @midwayCCA I'm glad I was able to help. Just mark this as the answer for the + rep.. :-)

Comment: can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355973/editing-data-from-database-using-modal-php